# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to java.security.PrivateKey

Tags: bouncycastle, pem

I would like to get "PrivateKey" from PEM file (PEM file contains keyPair), I am successfully able to read public key from PEM file (something same code shown below), but when I am reading PrivateKey, it's giving me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to java.security.PrivateKey
    at com.bouncycastle.common.ReadPrivatePublicKeys.main(ReadPrivatePublicKeys.java:41)
```

I'm using bouncy latest version of bouncyCastle to read the private and public key

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.52</version>
</dependency>
```

The Java code which I've developed for reference. Any quick help what is going wrong here? Any BouncyCastle developer can help me?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;

public class ReadPrivatePublicKeys {
    private static final String PEM_FILE="/home/user/user.pem";

public static void main(String[] args){
    PemObject pemObject = null;
    PrivateKey privateKey = null;
    FileReader fileReader;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(PEM_FILE);
        PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(fileReader);
        pemObject = pemReader.readPemObject(); 

        if(!pemObject.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("CERTIFICATE")){
            System.out.println("Does not contain a certificate");
        }

        final byte[] x509Dataprivate = pemObject.getContent();
        final CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        privateKey = (PrivateKey) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(x509Dataprivate));

        if(!(privateKey instanceof X509Certificate)){
            System.out.println("Does not contain an X509 certificate");
        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    System.out.println(privateKey);
}
```

}

Comment: A certificate is not a privatekey (or keypair) and cannot be cast to a privatekey type. It can't even be cast to a publickey type; it *contains* a publickey but that is not the same as *being* a publickey; instead you can extract the (subject) publickey *from* a cert with `.getPublicKey`. But a cert doesn't contain *any* privatekey. There are other non-cert PEM files that do contain privatekeys (really keypairs) but privatekeys or keypairs are not certificates, and if your PEM file parses as a certificate then it's not a privatekey or keypair. This is true for both Bouncy and plain JCE.

Comment: @Dave - Thank you. How I can get PrivateKey from PEM file using BouncyCastle? As my whole code is dependent upon the Private & PublicKey. Please guide with code.

Comment: "PEM file" is not an adequate description; there are dozens of things that have PEM formats and can be in a PEM file. If you have a *certificate* in a PEM file, as your exception indicates, you cannot get a privatekey from it, not with BouncyCastle nor regular Java nor OpenSSL nor GnuTLS nor NSS nor CNG and not even with black magic, because a certificate *does not contain the privatekey*. You could try to *break* the publickey to produce the privatekey; if the key is extremely small and insecure this may be practical, depending on the key algorithm, which you didn't identify. ...

Comment: ... Of course if the key is weak enough to be broken, any code you run using that key is worthless for any real security purpose. OTOH if you actually do have some kind of privatekey (NOT a cert) in a PEM file, it depends what kind it is. Post the "----BEGIN" line and the next two lines, at least.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that your PEM is similar to the output of this (no encrypt)
openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 2048

Your POM should look like this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here are the code using PEMParser plugged from [BC test suite](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/c0d5ac5e62a6531f640bdfb4897a9fe95a0c9fdb/pkix/src/test/java/org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/AllTests.java)

```
package com.nguyen.eledra;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PrivateKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;

public class Main {

    private static final String PEM_FILE = "/home/xxxxx/mykey.pem";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        FileReader fileReader;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(PEM_FILE);
            PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(fileReader);
            PEMKeyPair kp = (PEMKeyPair) parser.readObject();
            PrivateKeyInfo info = kp.getPrivateKeyInfo();

            PrivateKey rdKey = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().setProvider("BC")
                    .getPrivateKey(info);
            System.out.println(rdKey);
            parser.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eledra - It's saying, java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair
 at com.xml.XPathExample.Main.main(Main.java:25)

Comment: Could you tell me how did you generate the PEM file ? without a proper input, it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

This exception can be due to improper PEM format of reading cerKey file.
Anyhow your current crtKey form is PEM only, but it need a extended form of PEM. You can try this -

```
openssl rsa -in cert.key -outform PEM -out cert.key
```